# Terraform: AWS Lambda with Image not updating

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have a new terraform script that is pushing a docker image to an AWS Lambda.  The script works well and correctly connects the fresh image to the Lambda.  I can confirm this by checking the Image URL as shown in the AWS console for the Lambda and it is the newly pushed+connected image.  However when testing the lambda it is clearly running the prior code.  It seems like the Lambda has been updated but the running in-memory instances didnt get the message.
Question: is there a way to force the in-memory Lambdas to be cycled to the new image?

Here is our TF code for the Lambda:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  function_name = "MyLambda_${var.environment}"
  role          = data.aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  image_uri     = "${data.aws_ecr_repository.my_image.repository_url}:latest"
  memory_size   = 512
  timeout       = 300
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  package_type  = "Image"
  environment {variables = {stage = var.environment, commit_hash=var.commit_hash}}
}
```

Comment: How are you testing? Are you sure you aren't specifying a `version` value when you test the function? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html

Comment: I'm making an invocation from server code and its not specifying a version for the Lambda call.  But the testing is also being done with the "Test" option in the AWS Console and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more searching I found some discussions ([here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17153)) that mention the `source_code_hash` option in terraform for the Lambda creation block ([docs here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#source_code_hash)).  Its mostly used with a SHA hash of the zip file used for pushing code from an S3 bucket, but in our case we are using a container/image so there is not really a file to get a hash from.  However, it turns out that it is just a string that Lambda checks for changes.  So we added the following:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  function_name = "MyLambda_${var.environment}"
  role          = data.aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  image_uri     = "${data.aws_ecr_repository.my_image.repository_url}:latest"
  memory_size   = 512
  timeout       = 300
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  package_type  = "Image"
  environment {variables = {stage = var.environment, commit_hash=var.commit_hash}}
  source_code_hash = var.commit_hash  << New line
}
```

And we use a bitbucket pipeline to inject the git hash into the terraform `apply` operation.  This fix allowed the Lambda to correctly update the running version.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, if you don't want to depend on bitbucket for this, you can add a data source for the ECR image:

```
data "aws_ecr_image" "repo_image" {
  repository_name = "repo-name"
  image_tag = "tag"
}
```

And then use its id as a source code hash like this:

```
source_code_hash = trimprefix(data.aws_ecr_image.repo_image.id, "sha256:")
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple thing to try out is to use something like the below:

```
image_uri     = "${repository_url}:${var.pipeline_id}"
```

In the `gitlab` environment, you can use predefined variables like  `pipeline_id` as the unique id, and it won't be repeated every time for any project in the gitlab environment and then pass this value to your `tf` module. The `latest` tag is always **dangerous**. If you are using CI/CD there should be a list of predefined variables that would come in handy.

This way you don't need to use `source_code_hash` for the lambda function. Also, set your ECR repo as `immutable`. Not needed here but it is the best practice.